# SQL: efficiently append incremental number to string, avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a set of records (table [#tmp_origin]) containing duplicate entries in a string field ([Names]). I would like to insert the whole content of [#tmp_origin] into the destination table [#tmp_destination], that does NOT allow duplicates and may already contain items.

If the string in the origin table does not exist in the destination table, then in is simply inserted in the destination table, as is.
If an entry in the destination table already exists with the same value of the entry in the original table, a string-ified incremental number must be appended to the string, before it is inserted in the destination table.

The process of moving data in this way has been implemented with a cursor, in this sample script:

```
-- create initial situation (origin and destination table, both containing items)
-- Begin

CREATE TABLE [#tmp_origin] ([Names] VARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE [#tmp_destination] ([Names] VARCHAR(10))
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UniqueName] ON [#tmp_destination]([Names] ASC)

INSERT INTO [#tmp_origin]([Names]) VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO [#tmp_origin]([Names]) VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO [#tmp_origin]([Names]) VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO [#tmp_origin]([Names]) VALUES ('c')

INSERT INTO [#tmp_destination]([Names]) VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO [#tmp_destination]([Names]) VALUES ('a_1')
INSERT INTO [#tmp_destination]([Names]) VALUES ('b')

-- create initial situation - End

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE NamesCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT [Names]
    FROM [#tmp_origin];
OPEN NamesCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM NamesCursor INTO @Name;
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @finalName VARCHAR(10)
    SET @finalName = @Name
    DECLARE @counter INT
    SET @counter = 1

    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [#tmp_destination] WHERE [Names] = @finalName)
            BREAK;

        SET @finalName = @Name + '_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR)
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
    INSERT INTO [#tmp_destination] ([Names]) (
        SELECT @finalName
    )

    FETCH NEXT FROM NamesCursor INTO @Name;
END
 
CLOSE NamesCursor;
DEALLOCATE NamesCursor;

SELECT *
FROM [#tmp_destination]

/*
Expected result:
a
a_1
a_2
a_3
b
b_1
c
*/

DROP TABLE [#tmp_origin]
DROP TABLE [#tmp_destination]
```

This works correctly, but its performance drastically slows down when the number of items to insert increases.

Any idea to speed it up?

thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  A cursor is rarely the best way to process data.

Answer (score 5):

Using a windowing function allows the duplicates to be numbered. You can also get the count from the destination table (will need where condition to strip off the suffix you've added):

```
select orig.names,
       row_number() over (partition by orig.names order by orig.names) as rowNo,
       dest.count
from ##tmp_origin orig
  cross apply (select count(1) from #tmp_destination where names = orig.names) as dest
```

An `insert` can be built from the above (new suffix is `rowNo + dest.count -1` if greater than zero).

Suggest you refactor the destination temporary table to include the name and suffix as separate columns – this might mean having a new intermediate stage – because this will make the matching logic much simpler.

Comment: This should give noticeable performance boost - "Suggest you refactor the destination temporary table to include the name and suffix as separate columns"

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, I cannot change the the destination table as it is legacy. Nevertheless, this attempt also produces duplicates that cannot be inserted in the destination table

Comment: e.i.: this doesn't work: INSERT INTO [#tmp_destination]
SELECT CASE WHEN [Suffix] = 0 THEN [Names] ELSE [Names] + '_' + CAST([Suffix]  AS VARCHAR) END
FROM (
 SELECT [Names],
   [rowNo] + [Count] - 1 as [Suffix]
 FROM (
  SELECT [orig].[Names],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orig.names ORDER BY orig.names) AS [rowNo],
    [dest].[Count]
  FROM [#tmp_origin] orig
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [Count] FROM [#tmp_destination] WHERE names = orig.names) AS [dest]
 ) RawTable
) a

Comment: @Starnutoditopo Note the parenthetical note at the end of the first paragraph: you'll need to refine things (too much effort to get the string operations just write with such limited test data).

Comment: @Richard note that there's a deeper problem, here: even with arrangements, the query can generate suffixes just by "counting" existing items and items to be inserted. But the newly generated suffixes may be in conflict with other ones. In a single execution, it would calculated that 'a' already exists, generating 'a_1', but this will conflict with the existing 'a_1' item. I don't see a way to make it work without a WHILE loop or a cursor.

Comment: @Starnutoditopo The where clause in the `CROSS APPLY` needs to take into account the naming in the destination table.

Comment: @Starnutoditopo if you are saying there maybe gaps in the values in the destination table (`a`, `a_2`, ...) then you need to state this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
insert  [#tmp_destination]
select  CASE WHEN row_number() over(partition by Names order by Names) > 1 THEN Names + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), row_number() over(partition by Names order by Names)) ELSE Names END
from    [#tmp_origin]
```

Comment: This attempt doesn't take into account items that already exist in the destination table

Comment: If that is part of the requirements then you should update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a cursor in that case. Instead, I would build the query using `ROW_NUMBER()`. This way you add a counter in your original table, and then use this counter to append to your [Names]:

```
SELECT [Names], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Names] ORDER BY [Names]) - 1 AS [counter]
INTO #tmp_origin_with_counter
FROM #tmp_origin

SELECT CONCAT([Names], IIF([counter] = 0, '', '_'+ CAST([counter] AS NVARCHAR)))
INTO #tmp_destination
FROM #tmp_origin_with_counter
```

Comment: doesn't ensure new value is unique, what if there exists another value with _<number>?